# Freemarker templates double inheritence (child extends parent extends grandparent)

Tags: freemarker, jbake

In Freemarker, how can I create a template that inherits from a template that itself inherits?

**Single inheritance** works fine with the `<#nested>` tag:

File `base.ftl`:

```
<#macro layout>
<html lang="en">
  <head>...</head>
  <body>
    <div>... (navigation bar)</div>
    <div class="container">
      <#nested>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
</#macro>
```

File `normalBase.ftl`:

```
<#import "base.ftl" as base>

<@base.layout>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
      ${content.body}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
       <p>Latest releases</p>
       <ul>....</ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</@base.layout>
```

How do I turn this into **double inheritance** where `useCaseBase.ftl` extends `normalBase.ftl` which extends `base.ftl`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works like a charm:

File `base.ftl`:

```
<#macro layout>
<html lang="en">
  <head>...</head>
  <body>
    ... // Shared navigation bar
    <div class="container">
      <#nested>
    </div>
    ... // Shared footer
  </body>
</html>
</#macro>

<@layout>
  ${content.body}
</@layout>
```

File `normalBase.ftl`:

```
<#import "base.ftl" as parent>

<#macro layout>
    <@parent.layout>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <#nested>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                ... // Shared sidebar
            </div>
        </div>
    </@parent.layout>
</#macro>

<@layout>
    ${content.body}
</@layout>
```

File `useCaseBase.ftl`:

```
<#import "normalBase.ftl" as parent>

<@parent.layout>
    ${content.body}
    ... // Shared content between all use case pages
</@parent.layout>
```

Now I can create `*.adoc` pages with `jbake-type` set to either `base`, `normalBase` or `useCaseBase` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement `extends` and `block` like Jinja2.

`extends.ftl` for defining macros.

```
<#if !blocks??>
    <#assign blocks = {} />
</#if>

<#macro extends ftl>
    <#nested />
    <#include ftl />
</#macro>

<#macro replace name>
    <#local value>
        <#nested />
    </#local>
    <#assign blocks += {name: value} />
</#macro>

<#macro block name>
    <#if blocks[name]??>
        <!-- replaced ${name} -->
        ${blocks[name]}
    <#else>
        <!-- default ${name} -->
        <#nested />
    </#if>
</#macro>
```

`base.ftl` for layout

```
<#import "extends.ftl" as layout />

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>A demo of FreeMarker extends directive</title>
</head>
<body>
<@layout.block "message">
    This is default message in base.ftl
</@layout.block>
</body>
</html>
```

finally, `index.ftl` like this:

```
<#import "extends.ftl" as layout />

<@layout.extends "base.ftl">
    <@layout.replace "message">
        This is the message from index.ftl
    </@layout.replace>
</@layout.extends>
```

Take a look at https://github.com/emesday/freemarker-extends .